# Is this a valid way to prove $f(x)=\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is not differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> **Claim:** $f(x)=\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Proof: If $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ then $f$ must be continuous at $x=0$ that is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=f(0) $. Now it is quite clear that $f(0)$ does not exist thus $f$ cannot be continuous at $x=0$ and so it cannot be differentiable here.

I feel like it is wrong but I'm not sure why.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For differentiability at a point, function needs to be first defined at that point. $\cos\frac{1}{x}$  is not defined at $x=0.$

Comment: So my proof is correct then. Jolly good. Thanks.